# Replacing every odd 'comma' with a 'colon' with in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integer like so:

```
print(list) = 
[3584, 71943, 74593, 78252, 79205, 85318, 86152, 92030, 93207, 96977, 100464, 102041]
```

This is a list of ranges of index values so I want to replace every odd occurrence of comma with a colon like so:

```
[3584: 71943, 74593: 78252, 79205: 85318, 86152: 92030, 93207: 96977, 100464: 102041]
```

I have tried several regex examples such as:

```py
re.sub(r'(\b\d{1,2}),',r'\g<1>:',result)
```

but I keep getting: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I have also tried converting this list to a string then performing the regex solution above but it still did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your output list is not valid Python code.  What output do you want here?

Comment: Your output is not a valid python syntax; do you want a `dict`? for list of range objects?

Comment: It looks like your input is an actual list. Did you try converting your input to `str` first? (That does not fix the regex, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regex for that. You already have Python code, so just use Python code to convert the list into a dictionary.

```py
numbers = [3584, 71943, 74593, 78252, 79205, 85318, 86152, 92030, 93207, 96977, 100464, 102041]
dictionary = {}
for i in range(0, len(numbers) - 1, 2):
    dictionary[numbers[i]] = numbers[i + 1]
print(dictionary)
```

Result:

```
{3584: 71943, 74593: 78252, 79205: 85318, 86152: 92030, 93207: 96977, 100464: 102041}
```

Note:

- don't use the name `list`, because it shadows the Python type `list`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this great and simple solution!

Comment: @VV_1026: sorry, need to go in steps of 2. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want string outputs, and not a dictionary or something similar:

```
ls = [3584, 71943, 74593, 78252, 79205, 85318, 86152, 92030, 93207, 96977, 100464, 102041]
paired = [f"{ls[i]}: {ls[i+1]}" for i in range(0, len(ls), 2)]
```

As noted, your input is a list of ints, and your desired output is invalid in Python. So this is a guess as to what you want - the other reasonable guess would be a dictionary of key-value pairs mapping from int to int.

```
ls = [3584, 71943, 74593, 78252, 79205, 85318, 86152, 92030, 93207, 96977, 100464, 102041]
paired = {ls[i]: ls[i+1] for i in range(0, len(ls), 2)}
```

Essentially, the colon in Python has semantic meaning in certain places. In a dictionary, for instance, in the second solution above, it defines a relationship between a key and a value. It does not have semantic meaning and is therefor an error inside a list - unless it's encapsulated in a string, in which case it's just another character.

Comment: Yes I needed as a str. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Nathaniel Ford, follow up Q: is there a way to use the str output and feed it into a variable that store this as index ranges to use to call from a data frame?

I was thinking of using np.r_ to concatenate all the output as index ranges like so
df_ranges = df.iloc[np.r_[paired]]

This results in a NameError: '{3584:' is not defined

Comment: Mm, that's a little more involved than is reasonable for a comment. Just ask a new question with the code that you're struggling with!

Answer (score 0):

Your output is suit for dictionary type. You could use dictionary comprehension with `zip` function to slice the list from index 0 with 2 step (even) and from index 1 with 2 step (odd) as key and value pairs.

```
lst = [3584, 71943, 74593, 78252, 79205, 85318, 86152, 92030, 93207, 96977, 100464, 102041]
dct = {k: v for k, v in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2])}
print(dct)

# {3584: 71943, 74593: 78252, 79205: 85318, 86152: 92030, 93207: 96977, 100464: 102041}
```